# Sort specific range of columns in vb6 listview

Tags: vb6

sample listview items:

```
1 c c 
2 b b 
3 a a
4 e e 
5 d d
```

how can I sort rows 2-4 only?

I'm using this simple code for sorting but I'd like to exclude some rows (row 1 and 5)

> Me.lstReport.SortKey = 1
>   Me.lstReport.Sorted = True

desired output:

```
1 c c (exclude)
3 a a (sorted)
2 b b (sorted)
4 e e (sorted) 
5 d d (exclude)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate a bit, as it stands it's not very clear what you're asking, what you've tried, and what's not working.

Comment: hi, I've already modified the description, hope it's more clear now